# Dequeue styles with query doesn't work

Tags: css, hooks, actions, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

In my theme there is the following code (that is printing some inline css on the head of my site)

```
final class Design_Scheme {



/**
 * Design_Scheme constructor.
 */
private function __construct() {
    $this->hooks();
}



/**
 * Setup Hooks
 */
public function hooks() {
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'header_style_css' ), 11 );
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'footer_style_css' ), 11 );
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'global_style_css' ), 11 );
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'badges_style_css' ), 11 );
    add_action( 'wp_head', array( $this, 'set_mobile_address_bar_color' ) );
}

public function header_style_css() { ... 
public function footer_style_css() { ...

}
```

and i have been trying to Dequeue some styles from the hook but with no success.
I have tried everything, but doesn't work.

```
function remove_inline_style(){
if ( is_page( 'live' ) ){
wp_dequeue_script('header_style_css');
wp_deregister_style('header_style_css');
   }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_inline_style', 999 );
add_action( 'wp_head', 'remove_inline_style', 999  );
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'remove_inline_style', 999 );
add_action( 'init', 'remove_inline_style', 999 );
```

Any help or ideas what i am doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Last part of your code from functions.php?

Comment: are you sure that `header_style_css` is the name of the style, and not the name of the function the theme uses? The code in your question is incomplete, and the order that hooks run in is important ( you can't dequeue a script _before_ it's been enqueued ). Also, where is your code located?

Comment: @TomJNowell  you can see the full php file that make use of the css here https://pastebin.com/j94PSUAX . I am not sure where should i look . In the html is printed <style id='theme-primary-style-inline-css' type='text/css'> . Tried to use theme-primary-style-inline-css but it seems its not the handler.

The files name is design-scheme.php and the path of the file \wp-content\themes\mytheme\includes\front\design-scheme.php

Comment: @anton check my comment please

Comment: I also tried 

function remove_more_scripts() {
  remove_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'header_style_css', 12 );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_more_scripts', 999 );
add_action( 'wp_head', 'remove_more_scripts', 999  );
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'remove_more_scripts', 999 );
add_action( 'init', 'remove_more_scripts', 999 );

but dont work.

Comment: @Honoluluman that's the code from the theme, but I was specifically asking about your attempts to dequeue, where are you attempting to dequeue?

Comment: Also, there is no `header_style` inline css being added in that file. There are two other styles added using different names, and your own comment says `theme-primary-style-inline-css` but there is no `theme-header_style_css-inline-css`

Comment: @TomJNowell thank you very much for your help :) I am attempting to dequeue in my functions.php in the child theme. 

I've been trying to search inside themes files and all i could find is a small js code https://pastebin.com/TBndJ2Wg that is related with the night and day mode functionality of the theme, which i believe is not related to the css print out. 

And in the theme-setup.php https://pastebin.com/ZZHrFc4X Enqueue styles section.  If i try dequeue 'theme-primary-style' it removes the entire themes .css file, which i don't want. I only want to remove the printed 'header_style_css'

Comment: Ok so dequeueing is the wrong word/phrase to use as you do not want to dequeue the main stylesheet, you want to prevent the inline CSS being added. You should unhook the actions that add the inline styling instead. Have you contacted the theme author/provider?

Comment: Unfortunately i run out of support from the author/provider (my subscription expired).
But yes i found that the inline css is being added from wp_add_inline_style() and i could use add_action( 'wp_print_styles', function()
{
    // Remove previous inline style
    wp_styles()->add_data( 'theme-primary-style', 'after', '' );    

} ); and it works as it removing all the inline styling. But if i just want to unhook the action 'header_style_css'? How to syntax the function?

Comment: @Honoluluman, that `header_style_css()` function is not a global function; it's a class method, so when using it with `remove_action()`, you need to use the object method (more details [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php)), e.g. `array( $object, 'method' )`. And in your case, that object is `Design_Scheme::get_instance()` - see at the very bottom [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/j94PSUAX). Also, note that we dequeue a CSS file using `wp_dequeue_style()` and not `wp_dequeue_script()`..

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much @Tom J Nowell and @Sally CJ .

As you pointed out, it worked with the below:

```
function remove_inline_style(){
   if ( is_page( 'live' ) ){
    

   remove_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( Design_Scheme::get_instance(), 'header_style_css' ), 11 );


   }
 }
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_inline_style');
```

thank you for your help.